# change laravel 5 login link

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to change all the link of `auth/login` to `my-login/login` (associated with the login, register, reset password), how to do it?

I already changed the `auth` to `my-login` from Route::controllers array in the `routes.php` and

```
return redirect()->guest('auth/login');
```

to

```
return redirect()->guest('my-login/login');
```

in the `Middleware/Authenticate.php` and also `action="{{ url('/auth/login') }}"` to `action="{{ url('/my-login/login') }}"` but sadly when I press the login button in the login form, I got this error

```
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found. 1/1 NotFoundHttpException in compiled.php line 7693:
```

and the link changed to `/auth/login` (expecting `/my-login/login`).

Any help, suggestions, recommendations would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

PS: this is the default login, register, reset thing that is already default when installing laravel 5, I just kinda modified it a little.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation the only thing you have to do is change the auth controller route in **app/Http/routes.php** file like this:

```
Route::controllers([
    'my-login' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);
```

If you would like it to be just "*domain.tld/login*" just change `'my-login'` to `'/'`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

I believe this address is hard-coded in the view, at `resources/views/auth/login.blade.php`. You'll want to update the `<form>` action.

Comment: I already updated the form action as I explained in this post.